# Android Studio add jar library error

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I have follow the instruction to add jar library but when i am going to synchronize the build grade then getting error.

```
Could not find property 'file' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@1a9bd9bb.
```

I am not getting what is error. please suggest.

> build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cws.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile =  new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"));
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/layout'] } }
}

def var = dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
     compile file  'libs/library-2.1.1.jar'
}
```

Comment: Post your build gradle

Comment: def var = dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile file  'libs/library-2.1.1.jar'
    compile file  'libs/bit-lib4j-1.4.10.jar'
    compile file 'libs/commons-collections4-4.0.jar'
    compile file 'libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar'
     compile file 'libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar'
    compile file 'libs/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar'
   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Build.Gradle file the code to add the library is 
    compile files('libs/acra-4.6.0RC1.jar')

The letter 's' in 'files' is missing from the command.

Comment: please tell  me which line have 's'  miss

Comment: the code you commented on before.  i.e  compile file 'libs/bit-lib4j-1.4.10.jar'  compile file 'libs/commons-collections4-4.0.jar' compile file 'libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar' compile file 'libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar' compile file 'libs/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar' }

Comment: it should be like this  compile files 'libs/bit-lib4j-1.4.10.jar'  or  compile file 'libs/bit-lib4j-1.4.10.jar'  or  compile file ('libs/bit-lib4j-1.4.10.jar') ????

Comment: Yes it should be  compile files 'libs/bit-lib4j-1.4.10.jar' compile files 'libs/commons-collections4-4.0.jar' compile files 'libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar' compile files 'libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar' compile files 'libs/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar'

Comment: sorry same error after change. and compile error on  both
(file and files)  is can not refer any argument

Comment: Please make sure that the letter 's' is added for all the external library used and after that select 'Sync now' option which appears at the top of the screen. From what I know the error specifying that 's' only.

Comment: thanks solved issue . compile files ('libs/bit-lib4j-1.4.10.jar'). use ( ) indicate its local  i think.